# Creating a view from 3 views in SQL

Tags: sql, join, view

I have 3 views:

v_sessions, v_clickouts and v_sales

I am trying to join everything to a single view based on these rules:

1. v_session.session_id = v_clickouts.clickout_id
2. v_clickouts.clickout_id = v_sales.clickout_id

I am able to do this using 'LEFT JOIN':

```
LEFT JOIN v_clickouts clickouts ON 
    sessions.session_id = clickouts.session_id 
    AND sessions.user_id = clickouts.user_id 
    AND sessions.click_type = clickouts.click_type 
    AND sessions.click_id = clickouts.click_id 
    AND sessions.cid = clickouts.cid
    AND sessions.project::text = clickouts.project::text 
    AND sessions.event_time::date <= clickouts.event_time::date
LEFT JOIN v_sales sales ON 
    clickouts.clickout_id = sales.clickout_id 
    AND sessions.user_id = sales.user_id
    AND clickouts.project::text = sales.project::text 
    AND clickouts.event_time::date <= sales.event_time::date
;
```

By having additional 'AND' conditions I am losing data from the right side due to some conditions not matching. I want to leave only the two conditions:

```
LEFT JOIN v_clickouts clickouts ON 
    sessions.session_id = clickouts.session_id 
LEFT JOIN v_sales sales ON 
    clickouts.clickout_id = sales.clickout_id 
;
```

And move all of the 'AND' conditions a 'CASE' statement which would create a new column for each 'AND', so the view could have additional columns like:

```
session_user_id_equals_clickouts_user_id    session_click_type_equals_clickouts_click_type  clickouts_event_time_is_less_than_sales_event_time
TRUE                                        TRUE                                            TRUE
FALSE                                       TRUE                                            FALSE
TRUE                                        TRUE                                            FALSE
```

I don't know how I would be able to achieve this by using the 'CASE' method.

Thank you for your suggestions.

**EDIT**

Sample data - I get it after the first join of v_sessions and v_clickouts:

```
session_event_time  session_id  user_id     cid     click_type_from_session click_id    clickout_event_time click_type_from_session     clickout_id       
2019-12-18 11:21    id_1        user_id_1   cid_1   type_1                  click_id_1  2019-12-18 11:21    type_1                      clickout_id_1     
2019-12-18 18:35    id_2        user_id_2   cid_2   type_1                  click_id_2  2019-12-18 18:38    type_1                      clickout_id_2
```

These two views are joined only by the `session_id`, I want to have a `CASE` method to determine for example if:

```
sessions.click_type = clickouts.click_type as 1
sessions.click_id = clickouts.click_id as 2
sessions.cid = clickouts.cid as 3
sessions.project::text = clickouts.project::text as 4
```

And this would lead to having 4 additional columns in the final view like so ( I've named the new columns 1, 2, 3, 4 for shorter names):

```
session_event_time  session_id  user_id     cid     click_type_from_session click_id    clickout_event_time click_type_from_session     clickout_id       1       2       3       4
2019-12-18 11:21    id_1        user_id_1   cid_1   type_1                  click_id_1  2019-12-18 11:21    type_1                      clickout_id_1     TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    TRUE
2019-12-18 18:35    id_2        user_id_2   cid_2   type_1                  click_id_2  2019-12-18 18:38    type_1                      clickout_id_2     FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE
```

As I am not displaying all of the parameters that I am checking the conditions for, I would only need columns stating either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, I have added sample data and the desired output, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
LEFT JOIN v_clickouts clickouts ON 
    sessions.session_id = clickouts.session_id 
    AND sessions.user_id = clickouts.user_id 
    AND sessions.click_type = clickouts.click_type 
    AND sessions.click_id = clickouts.click_id 
    AND sessions.cid = clickouts.cid
    AND sessions.project::text = clickouts.project::text 
    AND sessions.event_time::date <= clickouts.event_time::date
LEFT JOIN v_sales sales ON 
    clickouts.clickout_id = sales.clickout_id 
    AND sessions.user_id = sales.user_id
    AND clickouts.project::text = sales.project::text 
    AND clickouts.event_time::date <= sales.event_time::date
;
```